# Sound is playing multiple times when look at an object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm learning about `raycasting` in `unity3d` and facing a audio problem. What I'm doing is there is a `Main Camera` which attached with a script called `NewCast`. That `Main Camera` cast a ray to the cube which has a component called `box collider`. Ray casting is working fine, when looking at that cube. I'm playing a sound. It means when camera looking at that object ray is cast to the cube. But why audio is playing multiple times. I want to play that audio only one time, when i look at that object and repeat this procedure again and again. Package [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1H5fdK2PJAnRlUyY2MtWWE4LXM).
[image: Picture]

Code:

```
public class NewCast : MonoBehaviour
{

    private RaycastHit hit;

    bool playAudio1;

    [SerializeField]
    private AudioSource source;

    [SerializeField]
    private AudioClip clip1;

    private void Start()
    {
        source.clip = clip1;
        playAudio1 = true;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out hit,9f))
        {

            if (hit.collider.gameObject.name == "Cube")
            {
                playAudio1 = false;

                if (!playAudio1)
                {
                    source.Play();

                    if (!source.isPlaying)
                    {
                        playAudio1 = true;

                    }
                }
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everytime the collider is hitting, you're setting `playAudio1` to false so the next condition is always true and so the sound will always play...

```
if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out hit,9f))
{
    if (hit.collider.gameObject.name == "Cube"){
        if (!source.isPlaying){
            source.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to play only ONCE per look to object :

```
public class NewCast : MonoBehaviour
{


private RaycastHit hit;

bool soundPlayed = false;

[SerializeField]
private AudioSource source;


[SerializeField]
private AudioClip clip1;


private void Start()
{
    source.clip = clip1;
}

private void Update(){
    if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out hit,9f)){
        if (!soundPlayed && hit.collider.gameObject.name == "Cube"){
            if (!source.isPlaying){
                source.Play();
                soundPlayed = true;
            }
        }
    }else{
       if(soundPlayed) soundPlayed = false;
    } 
}

}
```

Comment: first i try this same logic, but it also play sound multiple times.

Comment: Look like there is a problem with isPlaying (something with default  clips). Try to assign the the audio clip directly in the audioSource (in editor). Or try assigning the clip (source.clip = clip1) before playing it.

Comment: I'm assigning clip in `Start()` function of a script

Comment: That's what i'm saying. Try it.

Comment: still same problem. you can download and check my package link above!

Comment: Have you tried exactly like this ?
        if (!source.isPlaying) {
            source.clip = clip1;
            source.Play();
        }
This is how they do in the doc. I'm at work now but I'll look your project tonight if I find the time

Comment: I do it same but nothing happen

Comment: I downloaded your package and it work perfectly (I did no changes). Maybe your editor needed to be restarted, happen sometimes. Or maybe I misunderstood your question, do you want it yo play only ONCE per look-to-object ? if so you need another var, i'll edit my answer.

Comment: yes i want it to play only ONCE per look-to-object.

Comment: Ok, I understand the playAudio var now. Look my edit then :)

Answer (score -1):

It's sometime since I used Unity, but `AudioSource` in unity is set to automatically loop. Check the script which has the `AudioSource` and make sure you uncheck "is looping".
[See the Unity Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource-loop.html)

So am guesing that if you add this to your Start() function you will be ok

```
private void Start()
{
    source.clip = clip1;
    source.loop=false;//only plays the once and stops
    playAudio1 = true;
}
```

Comment: AudioSource is uncheck, and this component is attached with the `Main Camera`

Comment: Check the properties of AudioSource and look for loop or something. Unfortunately I dont have unity open right now and I cant open it. (My computer is weak with little RAM, and am working on a critical project) or edit your script as above and tell us what happens